# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined - React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I keep getting this error but I'm not seeing where the issue is. When I try to submit the name, email, and password, this is what pops up. Not sure where I've gone wrong here. I've tried.

React Error Message

[image]

Here's the code I'm looking at. The server is running.

```
    const clickSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setValues({ ...values, buttonText: 'Submitting' });
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/signup`,
            data: { name, email, password },
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('SIGNUP SUCCESS', response);
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    buttonText: 'Submitted',
                });
                toast.success(response.data.message);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('SIGNUP ERROR', error.response.data);
                setValues({ ...values, buttonText: 'Submit' });
                toast.error(error.response.data.error);
            });
    };
```

Comment: When does it happen? when the request is successful or unsuccessful? it's either that errors returned by the server don't have a `response` property or maybe the `response` when the request is successful, is undefined.

Comment: either response.data is undefined or error.data is undefined... try console.log-ing with that in mind

Comment: The issue is in the catch block. The error does not have a response field. If the server has a response field it is possible that it is catching a different error. try logging the error argument. console.log(error)

Comment: that response right above is the entire answer